# DATETIME parametrised queries on the stack exchange data explorer

Tags: support, data-explorer

Is it possible to have DATETIME parametrised queries on the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), e.g:

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME = ##MyDate##
SELECT @MyDate
```

The output is usually completely unrelated to the input ('2010-01-01' converted to '1905-07-02') - date conversion functions don't seem to be much help either.

Comment: SEDE doesn't actually parameterize queries -- it's merely a string replacement. Adding the `:string` hint auto-quotes when that process happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME = ##MyDate:string##
SELECT @MyDate
```

AFAIK, SQL Server accepts strings for ANY datatype to be implicitly converted.

The snippet works on SEDE.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following:

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME
Declare @inputDate varchar(8)

Set @InputDate = ##MyDate##
set @MyDate = Convert(datetime, @InputDate)

SELECT *
From Users
Where CreationDate > @MyDate​​​​​​​
And CreationDate < DateAdd(day, 3, @MyDate)
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/s/840/using-dates

Comment: This didn't work for me - replacing the `SELECT` with `SELECT @MyDate` gave me 2008-01-01 when I entered "2010-01-01"

Comment: @Kragen - It needs to be in the format of `20080101` not `2008-01-01`

Comment: Oh, that also works - a completely different format from what I was expecting though.

Answer (score 1):

After posting this I also found that using "'2010-01-01'" (**including** the `'` quotes) worked with the example posted in the question.